# How to setup Quarkus to work with Postgis?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, postgis, quarkus

I am trying to run a simple example with Postgis but I am getting the error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect.registerColumnType(int, java.lang.String)'`

I know that the Dev Service rise a PostgreSQL 14.8.

My **pom.xml** have these dependencies:

```
       ...
      <dependency>
           <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
           <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
           <version>5.5.5.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
           <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
           <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
           <version>2021.1.0</version>
       </dependency>
       ...
```

And in my **application.properties**, I have the property:

`quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect`

How can I solve this problem?

While I can't solve it natively (quarkus dev services + Postgis), I'm trying the following solution:

Download the Postgis docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis) and create a database (test) and configured as below:

```
%dev.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
%dev.quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
%dev.quarkus.datasource.password=mysecretpassword
%dev.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
%dev.quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create

quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

My class is something like the code below:

```java
@Entity
public class Route implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(columnDefinition = "Geometry")
    private PGgeometry coordinates;
    ...
   }
```

I am trying to send this payload:

```json
{
    "description": "Route 66",
    "coordinates": [
    [0.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 0.0]
  ]
}
```

Then I created a RouteDTO like:

```java
public class RouteDTO {
    public String description;
    public double[][] coordinates;
}
```

and my RouteResource is:

```java
@Path("/routes")
public class RouteResource {

    @Inject
    RouteRepository repository;

    private static PGgeometry createPGGeometry(double[][] coordinates) {
        Point[] points = new Point[coordinates.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
            if (coordinates[i].length != 2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid coordinate format: " + coordinates[i]);
            }
            points[i] = new Point(coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1]);
        }
        LinearRing outerRing = new LinearRing(points);
        return new PGgeometry(outerRing);
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(RouteDTO routeDTO) {
        Route route = new Route(routeDTO.description, createPGGeometry(routeDTO.coordinates));
        repository.persist(route);
        return Response.created(URI.create("/routes/" + route.getId())).build();
    }
}
```

When I try to call the POST I got the error:

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.`

The image docker installed PostgreSQL 15.3 and Postgis 3.3.4

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Also tried:

- Docker image postgis/postgis:14-3.3 that install PostgreSQL 14.8 and Postgis 3.3.4, but I got the same endian error.
- Docker image postgis/postgis:9.6-3.2 that install PostgreSQL 9.6.24 and PostGis 3.2.0, but got the error: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect.registerColumnType(int, java.lang.String)'

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the package where I get the Geometry objects from **net.postgis.jdbc.geometry.*** to **org.locationtech.jts.geom.*** and small adustments in the code:

```
private static Geometry createPGGeometry(double[][] coordinates) {

    GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory();

    Point[] points = new Point[coordinates.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        if (coordinates[i].length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid coordinate format: " + coordinates[i]);
        }
        points[i] = factory.createPoint(new Coordinate(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0]));
    }

    return factory.createMultiPoint(points);
}
```